# Find difference of time in days in R

Tags: r

I want to find the **difference of time** in **days** from the variables stored in *2 different columns* named  &  in the dataframe  and store in a new column  in the dataframe

`dist_va_indx <- difftime(VADAT_DT, Index_Dt, format = "%d-%m-%Y", units = "days")`

I am using this code, but there is some error. How do i solve this?

Comment: Hi, check first if conversion is done correctly `strptime(VADAT_DT, format  = "%d-%m-%Y")` `strptime(Index_Dt, format  = "%d-%m-%Y")`. I bet there is a problem with date parsing

Comment: `difftime` does not have a `format` argument. Coerce to class `"Date"` with `as.Date(col, format = "%d-%m-%Y")` first, then compute the differences.

Comment: So as @GoGonzo suggests you need to make sure that `VADAT_DT` and `Index_Dt` have some sort of date or date-time format. Also, if they are columns in a   data frame (let's call it `df`), then you can use `dplyr` as `df <- df %>% mutate(dist_va_indx = difftime(VADAT_DT, Index_Dt, format = "%d-%m-%Y", units = "days"))`

Comment: @Valeri Voev, forgot to mention both the columns **VADAT_DT** and **Index_DT** are in <%d-%m-%Y> time format, but both the variables are in 2 different data sets. Eg: **VADAT_DT** is in data set <df_va> while **Index_DT** is in data set <OE>

Comment: From your code, how would R know where these objects are? Shouldn't you then refer to them as `df_va$VADAT_DT` and `OE$Index_Dt` correspondingly?